# How to create a separate instance for your subdomain on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

Creating a SUBDOMAIN in AWS EC2 and ROUTE 53.

I created an AWS EC2 instance on my website amusan.co using WORDPRESS (Bitnami).

But now I want to create a separate SUBDOMAIN like port.amusan.co to create my developer portfolio which I will not be using WORDPRESS, as I plan to use HTML, CSS AND JAVASCRIPT.

How can I make that work?

Answer (score 1):

you have to create hosted zone for your domain than you have to create the records in that you can select policy simple or as per your requirement and than there is option to name sub-domain in record name and put there your subdomain name and in the value save your ip address to which you want to route traffic thats it and click on save

Answer (score 0):

**Create a hosted zone for the subdomain in Route 53**
Create a hosted zone with the same name as the subdomain that you want to route traffic for, such as acme.example.com. To do this:

Open the `Route 53` console.
In the navigation pane, choose `Hosted zones`.
Choose `Create hosted zone`.
In the right pane, enter the name of the subdomain (such as some.example.com). `Note`: For more information, see DNS domain name format.
For **Type**, accept the default value of `Public hosted zone`.
Choose `Create hosted zone`.

**Find the name servers that were assigned to the new hosted zone**

When you create a hosted zone, Route 53 automatically assigns four name servers to the zone. To start using the records in the hosted zone for the subdomain, create a new name server (NS) record in the hosted zone for the domain (example.com). The name of the NS record must be the same as the name of the subdomain (acme.example.com).

After creating the hosted zone for the subdomain, expand the Hosted zone details dropdown list for the subdomain in the hosted zone (acme.example.com). In the right pane, copy the names of the four servers listed as the Name servers under Hosted zone details.

**Add NS records to route traffic to your subdomain**

Select the hosted zone for the domain (example.com). Be sure not to select the name of the subdomain (some.example.com).
In the hosted zone for the domain, choose Create record.
For Name, enter the name of the subdomain.
For Value, enter the names of the name servers.
For Record type, choose NS - Name servers for a hosted zone.
For TTL (Seconds), select a more common value for an NS record, such as 172,800 seconds.
For Route Policy, choose Simple routing.
Choose Create Records.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But I can't still figure this out. I created a new hosted zone with sub.domain.com then I copied the NS name servers. I created a new record inside domain.com with the sub.domain.com and I input the subdomain name servers NS to create the record. But it's still not working

Comment: Did you add A records for the new instance? You'll need to put the public IP address of the instance. And do you have an elastic IP assigned to the instance? If not, it's better to assign it and add it as the IP address of the instance in the records.

Comment: You mean I have to create a new instance for the subdomain e.g sub.domain.com? If yes, after creating the new instance, what next?

Comment: You need to add A records with the IP of the instance. You can refer to this article https://bismobaruno.medium.com/configure-subdomain-to-amazon-ec2-with-amazon-route-53-1cb956c6a542

Comment: Thank you so much ♥️ The subdomain now works. But it's pointing to my WordPress website. I will like it to point to my developer portfolio. So when people visit sub.domain.com it point to my portfolio and when people visit domain.com it point to my WordPress site. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you add an A record to the subdomain to point to the 2nd instance?